# MySQL max selecting max value but pairing with incorrect row

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

I'll start off by showing you what my database looks like with some example data:

```
| id | type | id_user | date |
| 0  |  0   |   1     |   1  |
| 1  |  0   |   2     |   2  |
| 2  |  1   |   1     |   3  |
| 3  |  0   |   3     |   4  |
| 4  |  0   |   1     |   5  |
| 5  |  1   |   1     |   6  |
```

What this is tracking is when people leave or join groups and I'm trying to get how many people are in a group.

For example this tables history would look like:
(type 0 = joins, type 1 = leaves)

```
user 1 joins at time 1
user 2 joins at time 2
user 1 leaves at time 3
user 3 joins at time 4
user 1 joins at time 5
user 1 leaves at time 6
```

So if I where to query how many people are in the group it would be 2 because user 1 left 2 times and there are only user 2,3 in the group now.

I've been playing around for the past hour and a half but cant seem to get anything to work. I'm really confused with MAX() because its not returning what I would think is the correct result (though I'm aware I'm doing something completely wrong)

```
SELECT *,MAX(date) from myTable GROUP BY id_user
```

The above is my current thinking but its not giving me anything that I want.

I went into PHPMyAdmin and tried very simple MAX() just to get the largest date (I know you can do that by ORDER BY date DESC but that's not what I'm looking for. This is just a test):

```
SELECT *,MAX(date) from myTable
```

This, however, would return the first row in the list. So I played around a little more and put in a MAX(date) as D and what I found was it was really returning the first column and then slapping on the highest date:

```
| id | type | id_user | date | D |
| 0  |  0   |   1     |   1  | 6 |
```

I've tried googling this and looked through other SO questions but can't find anything that fixes my problem. If anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong with MAX or has any suggestions on approaches to this I'd be really grateful. (I have a feeling my query will have to be much more intensive.) Anyways, thanks.

Comment: See GROUPWISE max. If you're still struggling, provide a sqlfiddle together with the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to get the count of people in the group is:

```
select sum(case when type = 0 then 1
                when type = 1 then -1
           end)
from myTable
```

Getting the list of people is a bit more challenging.  You want people who entered but have not left.  Presumably, someone could enter and leave multiple times.  To solve this, let's count per person and use logic on that:

```
select id_user
from myTable
group by id_user
having sum(type = 0) > sum(type = 1)
```

Comment: This is such a simple way! I don't know why I didn't realize if the person joins more than they leave, then they're in the group. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE date = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM myTable)
```

It gives all the record where the date is bigger than the other.

I'm not sure that your problem is this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused by this part of your question:

> So if I where to query how many people are in the group it would be 3 because user 1 left (2 times).

Surely there are 2 people in the group since user 1 joins at time 1, leaves at time 3, joins at time 5 and then finally leaves at time 6? This would leave just users 2 & 3 in the group.....

Anyway - this query will give you the number of people currently in the group:

```
select count(*) as peopleInGroup
from
(
select id_user,
max(case when type = 0 then date else 0 end) as lastJoinDate,
max(case when type = 1 then date else 0 end) as lastLeaveDate
from groupLeave
group by id_user
) t
where t.lastJoinDate > t.lastLeaveDate;
```

Comment: Wow, you are right it would be 2 not 3. I was extremely tired at that point. Anyways, I tested this out and it does work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) as peopleingroup from(SELECT MOD(count(*), 2) as  cnt FROM `tbl_name` group by `id_user`) as main where cnt=1
```

Answer (score 0):

you should have a group by group but you have no group field.

```
SELECT sum( case when type = 0 then 1 else 0 end) - 
sum( type) as count_group from myTable ;
```